# How to handle recent apps navigation button in android studio?

Tags: java, android, navigation-drawer, navigationview, onpause

I have a NavigationView in my app. I want to open the NavigationView when resent apps navigation button is clicked. I tried this:

```
@Override
    protected void onPause () {
        if(!(drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START))){
            drawer.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } 
        super.onPause();
    }
```

But it opened recent apps and NavigationView together. Is there any way to open NavigationView when recent app button is clicked?

Answer (score 0):

> I tried this

`onPause()` is not unique to your desired scenario. There are many things that trigger `onPause()`, including system HOME navigation and configuration changes (e.g., screen rotation).

> Is there any way to open NavigationView when recent app button is clicked?

No:

- There may not be such a button, such as on the millions of devices that use gesture navigation
- Apps are not informed about when that button gets clicked
- Apps cannot interfere with the operation of that button